# Open and close ng-bootstrap alert component (ngb-alert)

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

Consider the following StackBlitz:

[AlertComponent](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-to9vlk)

As we can see we have two buttons that make show or hide the alert. The problem is that when closing the alert through the symbol to close (X), the alert does not show again even if you press the false button. To get to show the alert again, I have to press the button true and then the button false so that this alert will be shown again. Why is this happening? I would like an explanation. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The staticAlertClosed flag of the inner component is an input, but the inner component changes its value so

- setting the outer value to false by pressing the false button passes the false value as input to the inner component, and the alert is being displayed. The value of the flags are `false` in the outer component, and `false` in the inner component.
- closing the alert using its close button sets the inner component flag to true, making the alert disappear. The value of the flags are `false` in the outer component, and `true` in the inner component.
- clicking the `false` button in the outer component sets the value of the outer flag to false. But the value was already false. So the value doesn't change, and Angular thus doesn't pass the value to the input of the inner component: it hasn't changed. That explains the problem. The value of the flags are `false` in the outer component, and `true` in the inner component.
- clicking the true button makes the value of the flag in the outer component change. So it's passed again to the inner component. The value of the flags are `true` in the outer component, and `true` in the inner component.
- clicking the false button  makes the value of the flag in the outer component change. So it's passed again to the inner component. The value of the flags are `false` in the outer component, and `false` in the inner component. The alert is being redisplayed.

In short: don't modify the value of an input from the component receiving that input. Only the parent component should modify the input value. To fix this, you could use bidirectional binding.
Here's [a demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-to9vlk-unht23?file=app%2Falert-basic.ts).

Comment: Ok, so what should I do to achieve, that when closing the alert it can be shown again, according to a parameter sent by the parent component?

Comment: That's already part of my answer. refresh it, and click the demo link at the end.

Answer (score 1):

I have found an issue. When you click on exit sign inside AlertComponent **you only trigger a change in staticAlertClosed variable, but you do not change the value of variable in AppComponent**.

There are several ways to fix it, but here is what I have done.

Stackblitz link - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-to9vlk-nyog3i?embed=1&file=app/app.component.html

I have hooked the output event with variable in AppComponent. See the source code for more information